how can find "MSE" Mean Square Error solution?
Could someone explain how the formula above has been transformed into the one below? I heard that by taking the derivative, we can arrive at it, but I couldn't find it in any book. Does anyone know how to convert the upper formula to the lower one?
book, if you know the anwser please help...

StackOverflow is for questions about programming.  You can ask questions about mathematics at [math.se], or statistics at [stats.se].  When you do, make sure you actually include the equation in question, since it seems to have been left out here. Those sites support MathJax formatting so it would be better to retype the equation instead of using a photo or screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
